# Conversion of pymongo query from string to double after pipeline

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm currently running a mongoDB query using pyMongo, where I want to return the contents of an array stored in each object in the database, under the name 'TR Trace'. However, the data in the JSON object is stored as string, and I need to convert it to a double before I insert into a list, which I'm finding troublesome. Here is my query:

```
pipeline = [{'$match':{"Timestamp":{'$gte':m(), '$lt':current()},

    'Frequency Survey Reference':{'$regex':'Ch2'}}},

    {'$group': {
        '_id': '$Timestamp',
        'Trace' : {'$push': '$TR Trace'}
    }},

    {'$sort': {'_id': -1}},

    #{'$limit': 1}
    ]

get_tr = collection.aggregate(pipeline, allowDiskUse=True)

tr = list(get_tr)
```

I tried this, to do the conversion, and got the corresponding error:

```
get_tr = get_tr.astype(np.float)

AttributeError: 'CommandCursor' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

And I've been a bit lost ever since. Am I performing the conversion at the the right point?

Comment: You can convert from _string_ to _double_ within the pipeline, at any stage using the [$toDouble](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDouble/index.html) aggregation operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`$toDouble`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDouble/#todouble-aggregation) aggregation pipeline operator. Change

```
'Trace' : {'$push': '$TR Trace'}
```

to

```
'Trace' : {'$push': {'$toDouble': '$TR Trace'}}
```

Also `get_tr = get_tr.astype(np.float)` will not work as `aggregate()` returns a cursor for iterating.